# Finding the short in my receiver (AMP circuit)

Tags: transistors, amplifier, audio, receiver

I will be glad to get your help to solve the mystery in my MARANTZ-SR4500 receiver..
The problem is that after turning on the AMP I got PROTECT MODE and it turned off.
[image: FR-CH]
I find out that the source of the short is the Front Right channel, and I find out that 2 transistors, Q658 and Q652 got jammed. I replaced them to a new ones.
after turning on the amp I got PROTECT MODE again,
I find out that I didn't replaced the emitter resistor (R657 - that also got burned), so I replace it and I turned on the power again, in this point I got PROTECT  MODE again and the new R657 got jammed again(got very hot..). I checked the Q658 and Q652 and they was jammed again!
I dont know what else to do, what can cause this short? why does the transistors got jammed again?

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 2):

When the power transistors attached to the heatsink shorted, normally all associated components such as the emitter resistor, base resistor, its base pre-driver transistor and the low ohmic resistors around it will go along too...

Standard troubleshooting method for this type of amplifier is, after replaced all shorted transistors and all of the opened/partially burnt resistors, DONT apply power yet..!!

What you got to do is, temporarily cut the Vcc+ and Vcc- to the amplifier and insert a 22 ohms, 2Watts resistor in each of those power lines. Meaning, these resistors will limit any dangerous (transistor killing current) if some other fault still remains in the amp. If your amp is fault free, it will consumes only about  50mA (depends on bias strength) in its both power lines. You can verify this by measuring voltage across the resistor and divide by the resistance. Basic ohms law.

If the 22 ohm resistors heats up rapidly, it means there is cross current flowing through both power transistors.  If only one of your 22 ohm is heating up, there is a short from that power line to ground through some other component.

Relatively, these type of amp is very easy to repair if you understand well about the symmetry of the positive and the negative sides of the amp.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Steven, Thanks a lot for your advice.
I am sorry that it took so long for me to reply, I tried to get parts (not easy in my hometown..)
I Just tried to cut the VCC from the problematic branch,and adding the 22 ohm on the Vcc+ and - 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9-FWhDSq1shVzFrVnlpODFRNEU
I also replaced the Q652 and the Q658, and the R657.
I turned on the power and both of the 22 resistors were got very hot.
any idea what do i need to check?

Comment: Have you successfully repaired it?

Comment: nope, the amp is turning off, same PROTECT MODE... both of the 22ohm resistors got very hot...i need your advise, what is the next step?

Comment: What are the voltage drops across the 22 ohm resistors?

Comment: how can i measure it? the amp is turning off by himself

Comment: Disconnect R687 temporarily, this will prevent amp from going into protection. Your 22ohm can become very hot, do measurement as quickly. Whatsapp me at +60125822504

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see in the schematic, the protection cirduit is monitoring the pos and neg side of the output. when one side is higher than the other (non-symetrical sine) the protection transistor is biased high. So soosia is correct, try disconnecting or removing Q682 and determining which side is drawing so much current. I would also check the feedback xister Q517 which could cause the amp to enter a runaway condition overloading the pos or neg side causing full on condition of pos or neg side. Also, try putting your meter POS lead on the channel output and the NEG on the negative spkr gnd, and turn on amp (with Q682 removed) momentarily and notice which way voltage is, pos or neg, that gives you an idea which is your problem side (pos or neg). Also make sure you power supply is symetrical - in another words make sure if the pos side is 24VDC, the neg should be -24VDC with respect to ground. Both should produce 48VDC with respect to each other and clean (bad electrolytic can cause problems too).
Just my 2cents. W1ARQ

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, glad to see someone new answering questions! I couldn't help but notice your answer is one long paragraph (what we call a "wall of text"). Try breaking it up into a few paragraphs, that makes it easier to read and should get you more upvotes :)